# How to check if a column is empty or null using SQL query select statement?

Tags: t-sql

How do I check if a column is empty or null using a SQL select statement?

For instance, if I want to check:

```
select * from UserProfile WHERE PropertydefinitionID in (40, 53) and PropertyValue is null or empty
```

Comment: i want to know for that PropertyValue, how to chaeck that as i want.

Comment: Could you show us the table definition?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you wish to SELECT only those UserProfiles that have no PropertyValue set (NULL or no , is that correct?

Comment: Is your query for Sybase of Microsoft?

Comment: What does "empty" mean? An empty string, or something else?

Comment: This would be way easier to digest without the "PropertydefinitionID in (40, 53)" nonsense.  It draws away from the question and the answers.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM UserProfile
WHERE PropertydefinitionID in (40, 53)
  AND (    PropertyValue is NULL
        or PropertyValue = '' );
```

Comment: This works great. However if you have a situation (like I have) where a column with spaces should be treated as empty then just add LTRIM() and RTRIM(). Using Christian's example, this would be `or LTRIM(RTRIM(PropertyValue)) = ''`.

Comment: Love it.  @FumblesWithCode -- pretty good, given your handle!

Answer (score 24):

Here's a slightly different way:

```
SELECT *
FROM UserProfile
WHERE PropertydefinitionID in (40, 53)
  AND (LEN(ISNULL(PropertyValue,'')) = 0)
```

Comment: assigning empty string when null and determining the length of the column thereafter is great. thanks!

Comment: I like this - neatly covers everything including strings that only contain spaces, because `LEN('  ') = 0`.

Answer (score 12):

If you want blanks and NULLS to be displayed as other text, such as "Uncategorized" you can simply say...

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF([PropertyValue], ''), 'Uncategorized') FROM UserProfile
```

The above answers the main question very well.  This answer is an extension of that and is of value to readers.

Comment: `NULLIF([PropertyValue], '')` is much more concise as well.

Answer (score 9):

Here is my preferred way to check for "if null or empty":

```
SELECT * 
FROM UserProfile 
WHERE PropertydefinitionID in (40, 53) 
AND NULLIF(PropertyValue, '') is null
```

Since it modifies the search argument (SARG) it might have performance issues because it might not use an existing index on the PropertyValue column.

Answer (score 0):

An answer above got me 99% of the way there (thanks Denis Ivin!). For my PHP / MySQL implementation, I needed to change the syntax a little:

```
SELECT *
FROM UserProfile
WHERE PropertydefinitionID in (40, 53)
AND (LENGTH(IFNULL(PropertyValue,'')) = 0)
```

LEN becomes LENGTH and ISNULL becomes IFNULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
select isnull(nullif(CAR_OWNER_TEL, ''), 'NULLLLL')  PHONE from TABLE
```

will replace **CAR_OWNER_TEL** if empty by **NULLLLL** (MS SQL)

Comment: Not useful for the OP but useful for me. The right answer in the wrong place